# Is it possible to tweet from inside a facebook page tab url based iframe app

Tags: facebook, html, oauth, facebook-iframe, iframe-app

I am wondering if there is any way possible by way of which I may be able to tweet from a facebook app and then be able to track it. As far as I can understand I have to go through the oauth process to be able log a user in to tweet . However I don't understand how to do the oauth. While when  the user is connected already to twitter things work fine and one can tweet some standard line programatically but when the user need to be authenticated the login page does not come . I guess that is because twitter.com is not an allowed url for this app. I tried an alternate method that also failed which was to try and authenticate through a pop up but seems a popup does not fire inside a facebook iframe . Please any one has a suggestion on what alternate way i can use to do this ?

Comment: i'm pretty sure this will violate terms, but what if you add twitter.com as part of the app domain in the app settings? Not sure if it'll even work then, but do tell if you try.